# Human Favored Class: Sorcerer

Tags: pathfinder-1e, skills, sorcerer, class

First of all, I think this favored class bonus is ridiculously powerful compared to any other options available. It dramatically reduces the drawback of choosing a sorcerer over a wizard.

However, my actual question is about waiting until level 4 to put any points into it. I'm specifically referring to Mongoose87's post [here](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?172125-PF-Human-Favored-Class-Sorcerer). He mentions:

> Well, really it's 17 spells - who is gonna sacrifice 1 HP or skill
>   point for an extra zero-level spell?

But if you wait until you are level 4, you'll be able to learn 4 level one spells intermediately if you have 4 skill points to spend, right? That will make it 20 non level 0 spells unless I'm missing something.

Can anyone help clarify this for me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't wait to choose your favored class bonus, just like you can't put off feat selections or spending your skill points - or, for that matter, gaining your class features at your new level.

So, when you take first level in sorcerer, you have to pick between a hit point, a skill point, or a cantrip known.

If you could, though...  I have a GM Blob (PFS term for a high-level character who hasn't been created yet, the result of GMing PFS games and assigning credit to a character) that could "start" at level 11 - imagine me taking 11 extra 4th level spells with that?  And that's *why* you can't, if I had to guess.

Special thanks to Miniman for a [rules reference](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/character-advancement#TOC-Racial-Favored-Class-Benefits-Advanced-Player-s-Guide-).

Comment: You may want to add a citation - I went and checked you were right so that I could upvote, others might not.

Comment: @Miniman I'm actually looking now.  I know I found it once upon a time, but I'm having trouble finding it now.

Comment: I found it here: http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/character-advancement#TOC-Racial-Favored-Class-Benefits-Advanced-Player-s-Guide-

Comment: @Miniman I read that already (three times, the versions at PFSRD, PRD, and paizo.com).  It does say "each time you gain a level" but I was hoping to find a clarification that really says "RIGHT THEN".  Thanks ^_^

Comment: Ah, yeah. It's consistently difficult to find that sort of clear statement; I don't think it occurs to most game designers that people might not see levelling up as an atomic process.

Comment: Ah ok, I had a fundamental misunderstanding of skill points vs receiving a favored class point. Skill points are NOT used to get favored class ranks, you can only receive them once per level instead of an hp or skill point. Thanks for the answer.