# Where is it stated that you can gain spells as favored class option?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

This question [Human Favored Class: Sorcerer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/78484/human-favored-class-sorcerer) on here brought something up that I never heard before. After reading it I checked the SRD again and found nothing there.

In essence it states that as favored class option you can choose bonus spells instead of just +1 skillpoint or +1 hit point.

I never saw any such rule there so I'm wondering where this is stated? Or is this some kind of house rule?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a human alternate favored class bonus from the *Advanced Player's Guide*.  You must be using Paizo's PRD, not the more complete d20PFSRD that has all that info from the other books as well - [see towards the bottom of its Sorcerer page](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/sorcerer#TOC-Favored-Class-Bonuses).

Comment: Aaah never thought to look at the class option for humans (never had human wizards or sorcerers in any group).  Always thought they got similar bonuses there as all others. tnx

Comment: [Here's a link](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/sorcerer#TOC-Favored-Class-Bonuses) directly to the applicable section

Comment: [Or the Human page](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/core-races/human#TOC-Favored-Class-Options), they're listed in both places.  Whichever is more convenient for you ^_^ (It can be useful to have both, e.g. if you've settled on a race but are still picking exact class, or vice versa.  Happens to me a lot with casters - I know I want to play a caster of a certain race, but I'm not sure WHICH caster now there's so many options...)

Comment: Alternate favored class choices are from the Advanced Race Guide. The [paizo PRD](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/advancedRaceGuide/coreRaces/humans.html) has them listed, too, but you have to know where to find the rule first.